# $_GET Array to String

Tags: php, arrays, string, get

I'm working on a easier way of an existing page of mine and got a little problem.
I've tried to use `$_GET` to make it smaller, yet I get a lot of problems with this method.

Here's what I got:

```
$oc_a = file_get_contents('./'.$_GET.'/oc_info.html', true);
```

This is currently above this:

```
if ($_GET['pony'] == 'darkheart') die($header."<br><br>".$oc_a."<br>".$oc_b."<br>
        <table style='width=80%;'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ".$oc_c."
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        ");
```

And this is the error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/rikuu/htdocs/twitter/index.php on line 12
>   Warning: file_get_contents(./Array/oc_info.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/rikuu/htdocs/twitter/index.php on line 12

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong so far?

Comment: `$_GET` is an associative array of key value pairs, so this is almost certainly not what you want.  What are you wanting to get out of using `$_GET`?  I would guess you are trying to do something like `'./'.$_GET['pony'].'/oc_info.html'` but please don't do this without ensuring your document root is locked down to prevent something like `?pony=../../../../etc/passwd`

Comment: Well I'm trying to get the word after "pony=", in this case it's "darkheart"

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because $_GET is an array. For example, for the url `https://example.com/subdir?pony=cheerilee&apple=company`, this:

```
echo($_GET['pony']);
echo("<br>");
echo($_GET['apple']);
```

Will return:

```
cheerilee
company
```

So if your url was `https://example.com/subdir?pony=darkheart`, your code would look like this:

```
$ocA=file_get_contents('./'.$_GET['pony'].'/os_info.html',true);
if($_GET['pony']==='dearkheart') ...
```

Edit: as sberry pointed out, you should definitely make sure to lock down the directory. You could just check to make sure `$_GET['pony']` doesn't contain `..` or `/`

If you want to look at the variables you get with $_GET, run `var_dump($_GET);` which will return something that looks like:

```
array(2) { ["pony"]=> string(4) "dearkheart" }
```

This tells you all the array values in $_GET